Error in Express Js while setting up middleware
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at errorMiddleware (V:\MERN 2024\server\middlewares\error-middleware.js:6:29)
const errorMiddleware = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.status || 500;
  const message = err.message || "BACKEND ERROR";
  const extraDetails = err.extraDetails || "Error from Backend";

  return res.status(status).json({ message, extraDetails });
};

module.exports = errorMiddleware;

I was trying to implement a middleware by following a YouTube tutorial, but don't know where I went wrong.

Nothing wrong with middleware itself. u need to show other parts, how it is used. That error means your other function already responded to the client and here u are trying to modify response while it is already sent.

What other parts should I show, I only have imported the middleware into server.js and app.use(errorMiddleware)

If you want to get help, u need to provide as much information as possible. Nobody is going to read minds here. As already said, nothing wrong with the middleware but how it is being used. There are so much things to assume.

I have a user Schema file and using zod package I have validated the 4 fields it takes while registration of a new user. The 4 fields are username, email, phone and password. Now I have a controller where I have defined the functions for all pages of website and a Router for defining all routes. Ask me for any more information required.

If you have github, maybe I can show you all the code and then you can help me out. Tell me if it works...


So when you add a custom error handler, you must delegate to the
default Express error handler, when the headers have already been sent
to the client:

The delegation may be incorporated as below in your code:
const errorMiddleware = (err, req, res, next) => {
  
  if (res.headersSent) { // if the headers have already been sent
    return next(err) //delegate to the default error handler
  }

  const status = err.status || 500;
  const message = err.message || "BACKEND ERROR";
  const extraDetails = err.extraDetails || "Error from Backend";

  return res.status(status).json({ message, extraDetails });
};

Further on this issue:
The following code will reproduce the same situation. And cause the same reported error to occur. That is Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:....
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('OK');
  next('error');
});

To know more:
Inspect the the route handlers in the app, some route handler has codes like the above code. It calls the error handling middleware after sending the response to the client. The above one is an explicit call. However, it could be an implied call as well. It means some statements either on streaming the response or after sending the response would have failed and it caused to invoke the error handling middleware.  However the error handling middleware in the present is not aware of this case, and it again tries to send another response which causes the error.
By incorporating the code delegation to the default error handler, the second response will not occur and the error will be avoided.
Now the default error handler works on the logic that it simply closes the connection under such cases so that the error is avoided altogether.
For the original documentation, please refer to the link Error Handling
